# How can I mock the return from a generic wildcard

Tags: java, java-8, mockito, wildcard, java-stream

I'm trying to get my head around generics and wildcards in java 8. But I cannot understand why cannot mock this repository method. 
The code is pretty simple so should be easy to reproduce.

I've got this compiling error in "thenReturn" part of the "when"

```
The method thenReturn(Stream<capture#1-of ? extends Something>) in the type
OngoingStubbing<Stream<capture#1-of ? extends Something>> is not applicable
for the arguments (Stream<capture#3-of ? extends Something>)
```

the test:

```
@Test
public void ItShourReturnStreamFromRepository() {
    List<Something> list = new ArrayList<Something>();
    list.add(new Something());
    Stream<? extends Something> stream = list.stream();
    when(someRepository.getStream()).thenReturn(stream);     
}
```

the class:

```
public class Something {}
```

the repository:

```
public interface SomeRepository{
    Stream<? extends Something> getStream();
}
```

Can someone help with this?
Thanks!

Comment: Follow the recommendation of [the official tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcardGuidelines.html): *Using a wildcard as a return type should be avoided…*

Comment: How about adding some type to the interface? `interface SomeRepository<T extends Something> { Stream<T> getStream(); }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a general issue with wildcard types. To demonstrate it with a simplified, Mockito-independent example:

```
Enum<?> e = Thread.State.BLOCKED;

// produces "incompatible types: Enum<CAP#1> cannot be converted to Enum<CAP#2>"
Arrays.asList(e).set(0, e);

// works since Java 8
List<Enum<?>> list=Arrays.asList(e);
list.add(e);

// works even in older versions
Arrays.<Enum<?>>asList(e).set(0, e);
```

This points you to possible solutions that should work with the Mockito API as well. However, for designing an API like the `SomeRepository` you should following the general [“Guidelines for Wildcard Use”](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcardGuidelines.html):

> Using a wildcard as a return type should be avoided because it forces programmers using the code to deal with wildcards.

The `? extends` in the Stream’s element type produces a complication without any benefit. You can always create a `Stream<Something>` even from a source that has a more specific type, e.g.

```
SubTypeOfSomething subTyped = …

// from specific values
Stream<Something> s1 = Stream.of(subTyped);

// from existing collection
Set<SubTypeOfSomething> set = Collections.singleton(subTyped);
// note: this creates the stream directly from the source set
Stream<Something> s2 = Collections.<Something>unmodifiableSet(set).stream();

// if you really unavoidably have a more specifically typed Stream
Stream<SubTypeOfSomething> s3 = set.stream();
Stream<Something> s4 = s3.map(Function.identity());
```

The `Stream<? extends Something>` doesn’t offer anything the `Stream<Something>` doesn’t offer too.

It would be a different thing if the interface was typed instead, like following [RC’s suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41015423/how-can-i-mock-the-return-from-a-generic-wildcard#comment69240920_41015423):

```
interface SomeRepository<T extends Something> {
    Stream<T> getStream();
}
```

Then, you don’t have a wildcard anymore and a more specifically typed stream might offer a benefit.

Comment: _"The Stream<? extends Something> doesn’t offer anything the Stream<Something> doesn’t offer too."_

That's not entirely correct. With the former as a return type the method can return a Stream of a subclass of Something, with the latter it can't. External users of the method may not care about which particular subclass of Something it's getting, so forcing a fully typed interface may not always be the right choice. Sometimes a return type that uses wildcards is the most fitting.

Comment: @quiram the example using `Stream<T>` as return type *does* already allow the stream to have an arbitrary subtype of `Something` as element type. That still only has a benefit if there’s also code requiring the particular `T`. Having a `Stream<? extends Something>` has no benefit at all. Any code producing that stream can easily get adjusted to return a `Stream<Something>`, regardless of the original element type. Just adjust the last operation that determines the final stream type, e.g. `map` or `flatMap`. Like `stream.<Something>map(x -> expression-producing-a-subtype-of-Something)`.

Comment: I agree that a lot of code can easily be adjusted in the way that you suggested, but not _all_ code. I have a particular example myself, which is why I stumbled upon this question to begin with. You could have different classes _which you don't control_, one of them has a method that returns `Stream<SomethingA>`, the other returns `Stream<SomethingB>`. `SomethingA` and `SomethingB` both extend `Something`. I want a wrapper method that may call _either_ of this two and return the result. A return type of `Stream<Something>` won't compile, you need `Stream<? extends Something>`

Comment: @quiram or you append a simple `.<Something>map(Function.identity())`

Comment: true, that will work with streams, but not with all generics. In my case I don't really have a stream, so I can't map (I talked about streams to make it easier to explain, but it's actually a custom class). I guess the tricky part is that your proposed solution would work with the OP's sample code (and I agree it's a cleaner solution), but not with the more general question in the title.

Answer (score 0):

Putting aside matters regarding whether having a return type with wildcards is a good or a bad idea, this issue can be solved with Mockito by mocking via `doReturn().when()` as opposed to `when().thenReturn()`. The `doReturn()` pattern isn't type-safe so it's advisable to use it only when there aren't better options (like in this case). This way, your test can be written as:

```
@Test
public void ItShourReturnStreamFromRepository() {
    List<Something> list = new ArrayList<Something>();
    list.add(new Something());
    Stream<? extends Something> stream = list.stream();
    doReturn(stream).when(someRepository).getStream();
}
```